# One wire (+GND) serial communication. How to have a correct coupling?

Tags: avr, serial, communication

I'm a firmware developer more than a hardware designer. I've a doubt about an idea of mine.

I want to obtain serial communication between eight ATtiny85 (slaves) and an ATmega168 (master - It might be also an ATtiny85, but for this question is the same) using only one wire (plus GND).

I'm writting my protocol and it  begins to run. I've used the INT0 pin (PB2) of the ATtiny85 and the INT0 (PD2) of the ATmega168; these pins act as digital output when transmitting and, after transmission or as normal behaviour, become/are digital input to receive.

All the MCUs have the same power source, then if two MCUs transmit simultaneously there will be line conflicts and short circuits (if one transmits 1 and an other transmits 0). I want to avoid short circuits!

- Is it the right way to use resistors connected with each single pin
  limiting the current?
- If I use 9 resistors on the line, one for each pin, do the signal
  will have stronger attenuation?

At now I will avoid to use active chips other than the MCUs to manage the communications!

The MCUs are each one on a separated circuit, not on the same card, as it may seem in the following picture.

I apologize for the bad pattern, but I have not designed it yet. I have only a small breadboard with just two MCUs now.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkPyGK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The power symbol looks like GROUND to me in the picture, but whatever. Have you looked at the actual One Wire protocol (hardware and method of operation) already available in the industry?  http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/one-wire.html

Comment: Here is an overview of how 1-Wire bus works: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1796

Comment: There's no VCC in my scheme,I've indicated GND to explain that I've pull-up on GND.VCC should be connected at Ux chips.

Comment: You should not have anything between you Ux chips and ground.. that is a bad idea. I think you are getting electrically confused

Comment: My question is how to avoid shortciruit (if it's the case) between the pins (P1) if there's a simultaneus transmission.

Comment: @KyranF, if I don't have the pull down what's happen when all the chips are digital input? If I don't have the pull down I've a floating line and all CPU (Ux) may receive incorrect signals.

Comment: "Pull up" refers to pulling a pin to VCC. You are showing pulling to Ground. This is  "Pull down". The One Wire devices are similar to I2C bus, they have active pull down for "1", and release/open circuit for "0". They use high impedance input (any digital pin set to input works) for reading the bus. The protocol allows only 1 device to control the bus at any time, and the master initiates all communications. The ID of each device is used to request information from that device only, and there should never be any simultaneous driving of the bus by more than 1 device.

Comment: The firmware in each device should always read the state of the bus before turning on the active pull-down, if it's down for some reason, do not also pull down. You must do a lot of Data Direction Register (pin mode) changing during run-time, to swap between input and output port modes on the same pin.

Comment: Yes, I know the logic of communications. I know also that the master initiates the communications. But I know that in the configuration I'm using it may succed that two MCU (for error) initiate a transmission.

Comment: In that case, a simple 100 Ohm resistor in series from the DIO pin used for communications to the bus should be enough. You do realize that it doesn't really matter if more than one device pulls down, because they are just parallel loads coming out of the main bus pull-up resistor? The pins do not source current, they sink it. They cannot hurt other devices doing this, as long as no device sources current. If the only current comes from the bus pull-up resistor (or FET) then it's only an issue of broken communication, not damage to your Ux chips

Comment: I'm asking what hardware configuration I may use to avoid this shortcircuits. And, at this point, I may understand if it's possible to use the AVRs in this configuration. Why you say of a lot of DDR change? I have a DDR change only before packet transmission and at the end!

Comment: Do you means something like a bnc ethernet?

Comment: The DDR changes are obvious requirement to begin sending, but between sending "high" bits (while the bus should be high) it may be advantageous to change the pin back to input to read the level of the bus, and confirm that it's not being held low by something else, before continueing to send another "high" (active low) bit. If the bus is found to be in contention (something other than the device trying to transmit) then you can abort the transmission and try resending soon after the bus has finished being used.

Comment: I have the bus pulled-down, and who initiates a communications puts it high for a certain time. That give me the idea that who wants initiate a communication may observe the bus for an evaluable time then may initiate the transmission. It's no very sure, but may be!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect together any number of pull-down outputs and a pull-up resistor with no danger of short circuit. There needs to be scheme that avoids two outputs pulling down at the same time, but that is harmless if it happens. A possible scheme is for one transmitter to be Master which sends a 0 pulse every 10 seconds. All the other transmitters are Slaves who know their distinct addresses so that Slave #1 may send something 1 second after the Master pulse, Slave #2 may send 2 seconds after,.... and so on. This example is deliberately slow because the data rate will be limited by the capacitance of the signalling wire, which we don't know.

The one-wire protocol device that KyranF mentions is clever because it manages to get its power from the same line that it occasionally pulls down.

Comment: I have done some work on sensor chains using 1-wire protocol by Maxim. I used a 1-wire bus master IC which deals with the hardware protocol and timing nicely, plus I used a high side P-FET pull up for active and powerful supply current to end-devices, also allowing for much higher bus capacitance. Indeed as you say the whole process is slow in general, but for things like a chain of temperature or moisture sensors it was fine.

Comment: My protocol foreseen that the master sends a packet that contains the address of the slave that has to receive, and then waits the slave reply. But I would to have the slaves are able to send also in an asynchronous way, such as ethernet!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Ethernet was not always full duplex (allows both way communication), the problem with a single wire used for master-slave communication, AND multi-devices, is you basically cannot allow asynchronous/unchecked bus control by slaves. It must be carefully organized by the master, or as cuddlyable3 mentions above, using time multiplexing schemes.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini If you had 2-wire (plus ground) you could definitely try some tricky two-way or multi-slave communications in a more asynchronous, event-based method of communications

Comment: Yes I know, but in this period I'm unemployed and I have time to make some experiments ... :) I want use ATtiny85 using all its pins ... I might use also I2C, but ...

Comment: I don't think (obvious) to have full duplex communication with only one wire (expecially using digital signals) ... I know that bnc based ethernet was/is half/duplex.